# Issue with passing in variables with and event in python tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I am writing a simple 3d simulator with tkinter and I am encountering a problem with passing arguments through a function bound to an event.

my function is

```
def left(event):


    cam1 = 0
    cam2 = 0
    def render( cam1, cam2):
        w.delete("all")
        cam1 = cam1 + 5
        cam2 = cam2 + 2
        lol = 0
        w.create_rectangle(10+cam1,10+cam1,190+cam1,190+cam1)
        w.create_rectangle(40+cam2,40+cam2,160+cam2,160+cam2)
        w.create_line(10+cam1,10+cam1,40+cam2,40+cam2)
        w.create_line(40+cam2,160+cam2,10+cam1,190+cam1)
        w.create_line(160+cam2,160+cam2,190+cam1,190+cam1)
        w.create_line(190+cam1,10+cam1,160+cam2,40+cam2)
    w.after(10,render(cam1,cam2))
```

i want to be able to have cam1 and cam2 not be 0 every time i call the function but it wont let me pass in more arguments with the event, i use

```
w.bind("<Right>", right)
```

to bind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `after` call is incorrect.  You must give it a *reference* to a function. Additional arguments can be given. In your case it would be:

```
w.after910, render, cam1, cam2)
```

As for the binding, the most common solution is to use `lambda` or `functools.partial`. For example:

```
w.bind("<Right>", lambda event, arg1="something", arg2="something else": right(arg1, arg2))
```

Variations of this question have been asked dozens of times on stackoverflow. Try searching this site for `[tkinter] bind argument`. Your question should probably be marked as a duplicate, but it's hard to know which question is the best original question.